# Как отписаться от спам рассылки, если кнопки "отписаться" нет?

Tags: email, smtp, hosting, спам, whois

Некоторое время назад ко мне на почту начали приходить письма с адреса `nobody@google.com`, разумеется, это замена домена и имени:

```
From: Google Formulare <nobody@google.com>
```

Есть поле `Return Path`:

```
Return-Path: 3wSf3WAgJCLosnpfwqnp3fsij2.wzsnpfwqnp3fsij2.wz@trix.bounces.google.com
```

В самом начале письма указано следующее (мой логин заменён на username):

```
Received: from mxfront3g.mail.yandex.net ([127.0.0.1])
    by mxfront3g.mail.yandex.net with LMTP id EMNKG82z
    for <username@yandex.ru>; Wed, 19 Apr 2017 12:03:03 +0300
Received: from mail-io0-x246.google.com (mail-io0-x246.google.com [2607:f8b0:4001:c06::246])
    by mxfront3g.mail.yandex.net (nwsmtp/Yandex) with ESMTPS id dcXAA5fgfj-2vamDclh;
    Wed, 19 Apr 2017 12:02:57 +0300
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits))
    (Client certificate not present)
X-Yandex-Front: mxfront3g.mail.yandex.net
X-Yandex-TimeMark: 1492592577
Authentication-Results: mxfront3g.mail.yandex.net; spf=pass (mxfront3g.mail.yandex.net: domain of trix.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4001:c06::246 as permitted sender, rule=[ip6:2607:f8b0:4000::/36]) smtp.mail=3wSf3WAgJCLosnpfwqnp3fsij2.wzsnpfwqnp3fsij2.wz@trix.bounces.google.com; dkim=pass header.i=@google.com
X-Yandex-Spam: 1
Received: by mail-io0-x246.google.com with SMTP id d203so10465614iof.20
        for <username@yandex.ru>; Wed, 19 Apr 2017 02:02:57 -0700 (PDT)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться кто это отсылает (хотя бы как связаться с этим человеком), потому что ни отписаться невозможно, ни система фильтрации не реагирует на занесение этих писем в спам.

## UPD

`trix.bounces.google.com` - это доменное имя отправщика форм Google, как я понял. Когда кто-то приглашает кого-то посмотреть форму, то сообщение приходит не с `email` этого человека, а с `email` бота `Google Forms`.

Есть ли возможность узнать кто автор этой рассылки? Хоть какую-нибудь информацию?

Как можно заблокировать эту рассылку инструментами почты, но при этом не потерять возможность получать приглашения к формам Google?

Comment: Все адреса резолвятся (nslookup) (собственно, yandex уже это поверил при приеме письма), так что это не какая-то совсем уж левота... А часть `3wSf3WAgJCLosnpfwqnp3fsij2.wzsnpfwqnp3fsij2.wz@` в Return-Path наверное меняется от письма к письму?

Comment: @avp да, `Return Path` наверняка меняется. Кстати, дал ответ что узнал и что сделал, можете ознакомиться

Comment: Я прочел. Только  вот  **информации в тексте вопроса** этот ответ не соответствует.

Comment: @avp обновил. Так лучше?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Ответ основан на анализе тела письма, а в тексте вопроса только заголовки.

Comment: Лично я, проходя по ссылке из этого письма, попал вот сюда: Privat Club Social Assistance. Там обещают халявные деньги (от 200000 руб.) тому, кому они нужны: нужно просто убедить в этой необходимости. На мой взгляд это обычный лохотрон, кто именно его рассылает, узнать, конечно, можно, но я сомневаюсь, что на это стоит тратить драгоценное время.

Comment: Просто запостите жалобу на https://support.google.com/drive/contact/docs_abuse?hl=en&contact_typemaster=abuse&Action.Search=Continue&page=troubleshooter.cs&problem=abuse&stage=fm&visit_id=1-636286623544912977-3015887119&rd=1, форму удалят, автора формы забанят.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## UPD2 - Решение вопроса

## Собираем всё, что только можно собрать

В моём случае это:

Ссылки на Google Форму ([для примера одна](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeMNR_ecfTQUDje9D3EBF4U48bmSI5c7FYKEqKqfNvxkOR-DQ/viewform?usp=mail_form_link) - форма заблокирована `Google`'ом) - вряд ли поможет, но оставим на будущее.

Ссылки в письмах - http://fas.st/TLi4P, http://fas.st/0dY3s, http://fas.st/O65I7z + куча ссылок `bit.ly`

Длинные ссылки - http://affiliatelink.website/tds/ua7m, http://affiliatelink.website/tds/8k8d (пользуемся выпрямителем ссылок. Я пользуюсь этими: не работает [один](http://url0.ru/links/unshort/), идём на [второй](https://ciox.ru/check_short_url).)

## Пытаемся собрать как можно больше информации:

Информация о хостинге (кто предоставляет хостинг)

Информация из [whois](https://www.nic.ru/whois/) (контактные данные, где домен регистрировался)

IP ресурсов

Пытаемся осмотреться на сайте и найти какую-либо полезную информацию

**В моём случае это сайт http://affiliatelink.website**

На главной - картинка 404 (то есть не ошибка, а там, в принципе, больше ничего нет). Я попытался поискать какие-нибудь `url` с помощью `python` скрипта, но спустя полчаса я не нашёл ни одного.

Смотрим информацию в **[whois](https://www.nic.ru/whois/?query=http%3A%2F%2Faffiliatelink.website%2F)**

Домен зареган у `reg.ru`, контакт для связи с владельцем -
 `affiliatelink.website@regprivate.ru`

## Дальнейшие действия

Пишем письмо владельцу с просьбой исключить ящик из рассылки и угрозой обратиться в правоохранительные органы. Также пишем жалобу регистратору домена (у меня это `support@reg.ru`) и заодно просим уведомить клиента, чтобы он исключил ящик из рассылки, иначе его ждут разбирательства (вдруг почта не редиректится, а владелец домена не читает внутреннюю почту домена).

Ждём решения по поводу данной жалобы и, возможно, ответа от владельца домена.

А я также надеюсь, что письма, приходящие на `@regprivate.ru`, редиректятся на основную почту.

## UPD3 - Пишем хостеру

В whois есть специальные поля Name Server

```
Name Server: NS1.DDOS-GUARD.NET
Name Server: NS2.DDOS-GUARD.NET
Name Server: NS3.DDOS-GUARD.NET
```

Переходим на сайт хостера (у меня это https://ddos-guard.net), и видим, что они **предоставляют решения** для **защиты сайтов** и то, что мы ждали - безопасный **хостинг**.

Копируем наше письмо регистратору домена, немного изменяя его, и отправляем его хостеру.

Ждём решения.

Comment: "поискать какие-нибудь url с помощью python скрипта" - DirBuster и Accunetix в помощь